# Callback is not a function node.js, mongodb, res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I am trying to get data from a MongoDB collection so I created a database.js module to do this. One of the functions on the module was an exports.find function used to find data from a collection. I pass in a *callback* into the function because the Javascript is asynchronous and it takes time to retrieve data from the server. This is the code of the exports.find.

```
exports.find = (database, table, projection, callback) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err
        var dbo = db.db(database);
        dbo.collection(table).find({}, projection).toArray(function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err
            callback()
            db.close()
        });
    });
}
```

I then use this function in my index.js file to use the found data and send it to the client. I did this by passing in *res.render* into my callback.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    database.find('blog', 'blog-posts', {}, res.render('pages/index'))
})
```

Whenever I run this however, I get this error

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at C:\Users\21Swag\Documents\Coding\Blog\database.js:23:13
```

The error points to the database.js file when I call the callback.

```
callback()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is not a function, because you are already invoking it in database.find and then trying to call the return value of said function as your callback.

Maybe this will help:

```
const one = () => console.log(1)

const cbTest = (cb) => cb()

cbTest(one()) // Error: cb is not a function as it already returned 1

cbTest(one) // will console.log 1 as it is invoked correctly
```

Usually a callback is passed as an anonymous function like this:

```
database.find('blog', 'blog-posts', {}, () => res.render('pages/index'))
```

You can see the same pattern in the MongoClient.connect function/method. The second argument is the anonymous callback with (err, db) as parameters.

Comment: What if I wanted to pass in a parameter to the function. For example, I want to send my results to the client using res.render. To do this wouldn't I need to call res.render('pages/index', results) in my exports.find function?

Comment: Wrap it in another function without invoking it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me out a lot

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Could you accept the answer? :)